# Comparing the Induced Norm of a Matrix Product and its Submatrix Product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Suppose I have a matrix $F \in R^{m \times n}$, and a submatrix of $F$ is defined as $F_S\in R^{|S|\times n}, S\subseteq \{1,2,\dots, m\}$, where $S$ is the subset of row-indices in $F$.

What is the relationship between $\|FF^\top\|$ and $\|F_SF^\top\|$?

Comment: My guess is, it depends. However, I ran a few MATLAB simulations, and it seems that the inequality is $\|F_S F^\top\| < \|FF^\top\|$. I am still looking for a proof for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that

$$F_SF^T = (FF^T)_S $$

Indeed,

$$(F_SF^T)_{i,j} = \sum_{k=1}^n (F_S)_{i,k} (F^T)_{k,j} = \sum_{k=1}^n (F)_{s_i,k} (F^T)_{k,j} = (FF^T)_{s_i, j}$$

Now the problem is that $FF^T$ and $F_SF^T$ are in different spaces, so the initial question is tricky. Obviously, the norms cannot be the same norms !